# Contact Form Not Working on Mobile Browser Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am working on my first ruby on rails by following a tutorial, now deployed to production, I noticed the contact is working fine on PC browser message do get sent and delivered to mail but on mobile browser send button only reload the page with input again.

this is the html code

```
<%= form_for(@contact, :html => { :class => "form-stacked"}, :remote => true) do |f| %>
            <form class="contact__form">
              
               <h3 class="text-md ">Contact Us</h3>
               <p class="mb-5">Reach out to the world’s most reliable services.</p>
               
               <div class="input-group">
                  
                  <%= f.text_field  :name, required: true, class: 'input', placeholder: "Your name"%></br>
               </div>
               
                  <div class="input-group">
                  
                  <%= f.text_field  :Email, required: true, class: 'input', placeholder: "Email Address"%></br>
               </div>
               <div class="input-group-2 mb-4">
                  
                  <%= f.text_area  :message, required: true, class: 'input', rows: "4", placeholder: "Your Message"%></br>
               </div>

               
               <%= f.submit 'Send Message', class: 'btn btn-main' %>
                
                <% end %>
```

this is the controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:success] = 'Message sent!'
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Could not send message'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

log example of message sent from pc:

```
[55fef2dc-48af-448a-9af1-5d63774682c6] Started POST "/contacts" for 172.71.102.128 at 2023-01-17 12:46:11 +0000
[55fef2dc-48af-448a-9af1-5d63774682c6] Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
[55fef2dc-48af-448a-9af1-5d63774682c6]   Parameters: {"contact"=>{"name"=>"siri", "Email"=>"user@gmail.com", "message"=>"piytan"}, "commit"=>"Send Message"}
[55fef2dc-48af-448a-9af1-5d63774682c6]   Rendered /layers/heroku_ruby/gems/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/mail_form-1.9.0/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb (Duration: 1.7ms | Allocations: 834)[2023-01-17T12:46:11.726778 #1]  INFO -- : [55fef2dc-48af-448a-9af1-5d63774682c6] Delivered mail 63c6989313cac_1a3482043b@asi4her-588fcb97b9-c8d2m.mail (646.5ms)
[55fef2dc-48af-448a-9af1-5d63774682c6]   Rendered contacts/create.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 179)
[55fef2dc-48af-448a-9af1-5d63774682c6]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 3.2ms | Allocations: 1186)
[55fef2dc-48af-448a-9af1-5d63774682c6] Completed 200 OK in 671ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 7819)
```

Example of one sent from mobile:

```
[f272778b-c913-49f1-b407-e1c8b4288798] Started POST "/contacts" for 172.71.182.191 at 2023-01-17 12:45:53 +0000
[[f272778b-c913-49f1-b407-e1c8b4288798] Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
[f272778b-c913-49f1-b407-e1c8b4288798]   Parameters: {"contact"=>{"name"=>"siri", "Email"=>"User@gmail.com ", "message"=>"Hii",  "commit"=>"Send Message"}
 [f272778b-c913-49f1-b407-e1c8b4288798]   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.3ms | Allocations: 929)
[f272778b-c913-49f1-b407-e1c8b4288798]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 3.6ms | Allocations: 1899)
[f272778b-c913-49f1-b407-e1c8b4288798] Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2148)
```

Comment: For some reason your `"commit=>"Send Message"` is inside the contacts params in the mobile version but outside that hash in the regular version.

Comment: What mobile browser are you using? Have you tried others? Can you try it in several desktop browsers?

Comment: @Beartech samsung browser, iphone safari and chrome, desktop browsers are working fine

Comment: Right now Safari and Chrome mobile browsers are handling the request well, mails are getting delivered bt samsung and uc browsers misbehaving dont know why

Comment: That sounds like a bug for those browsers. But it could be that the HTML Rails is generating is considered "ambiguous"? I would get the HTML that a working browser is generating vs one that is not working. See where the tags differ. You might have to do a bit more manual HTML work in your form until the problem is resolved. I can't say it isn't `form_for` that is doing it, but you could always file a bug with them and give the HTML outputs vs the rails ERB code.